# Biblatex 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Texlive 2016

Tags: 16.04, package-management, latex, texlive, lyx

I installed Tex Live 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Now References are not working. When I use `biber` in LYX 2.2.2, I get the following error:

```
Biber error: Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected version 3.2.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber
```

it says,

```
texlive-bibtex-extra is already the newest version (2016.20160520-1~ubuntu16.04.1york1).
biber is already the newest version (2.6.0-0york1~16.04).
```

I guess, I have old version of `Biblatex`. I could not figure out how to install the latest version of `Biblatex`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not the standard 16.04 provided package; you are using a PPA (https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016 I think). Probably the problem is over there. Try to contact the PPA owner. Biber works just ok in my (stock 16.04, so TexLive 2015) installation. Good luck!

Comment: This is definitely a problem with the PPA. I have used the same PPA and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` to get `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.st‌​y`.
2. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/) download `biber v.2.6`.
3. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/) download `biblatex v.3.6`
4. Create two temp dirs: `mkdir tempbb && mkdir tempbl`
5. Uncompress `biber-cygwin64.tar.gz` and `biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz` to the temp directories:

   ```
   tar -zxvf biber-cygwin64.tar.gz -C tempbb/
   tar -zxvf biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz -C tempbl/
   ```
6. Move the contents of the files in the `tempbl` temp directory to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/
   ```
7. Move the `biber` bin from your temp directory to  `/usr/share/texlive/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/
   ```
8. Run `mktexlsr`
9. Test that everything is working fine.